# I'm soooo tired - What am I?

Tags: riddle

I'm soooo tired!

My feet hurt...

I'm so happy I look like there's two!

It's so warm this summer...

It's so bloody cold at night, there's three of me.

Our unlikely alliance will rain down upon you.

Yay! Complicated food!

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer is

> Dog

I'm soooo tired!

> "Dog-tired" means extremely tired or worn out.

My feet hurt...

> "My dogs are barking" is an idiom that means your feet hurt.

I'm so happy I look like there's two!

> To be "like a dog with two tails" is to be very happy.

It's so warm this summer...

> "Hot dogs" are generally eaten in summer. 
> **Edit:** The intended answer from Brent Hackers is "Dog Days" - the hot sultry days of summer.

It's so bloody cold at night, there's three of me.

> A ["three dog night"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/three+dog+night) is a very cold night.

Our unlikely alliance will rain down upon you.

> It's raining "cats and dogs" (an unlikely alliance, indeed).

Yay! Complicated food!

> I think this refers to "making a dog's dinner of something" i.e, to make it unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Hex.  On form as always.  You know, you probably solve about 50% of my puzzles. +1

Comment: I have to admit I do look out for your puzzles as I enjoy figuring them out and the answer is always very satisfying. This is a great one and I wish I could give you more credit than just a +1.

Comment: That's cool.  By the way, yours is just as good, but the answer I had in mind for "It's so warm this summer" ended in "days"

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> Mumble, the penguin from happy feet

I'm sooo tired! 
My feet hurt...

> He had to tap dance to get a girl

I'm so happy I look like there's two

> They made a second movie, Happy Feet 2

It's so warm this summer... 
It's so bloody cold at night, there's three of me

> Third movie?

Ok I only got this far before realizing this quite probably isn't the answer, I'm just gonna leave it up on the off chance that I got it right.

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for...  It's imaginative though.

Comment: First thing I thought of too haha